# checking whether or not entityLoad with filtercriteria returned a result or not

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-9

I am calling entityLoad like this:

```
currentSubmission =  entityload("EventSubmission", { eventID = variables.eventID, profileID = variables.profileID, true }
```

How do I check if the entityLoad has returned a record or not?  If there is a match on the filtercriteria, an Object is returned.  If there is no match, nothing is returned and the variable currentSubmission doesn't exist.

The problem I am finding is that if I use:

a. isObject(currentSubmission), gives an error when nothing is returned, as currentSubmission doesn't exist.

b. isDefined(currentSubmission), gives an error when something is returned as you can't perform isDefined on an object.

So the quesiton is, what method should I use to determine whether or not entityLoad returned a result or not?

Here is the full method I am trying to put together.  Basically, I want to load an entity based on some filter criteria and return it, if there is no matching entity, then return a new Empty entity.

```
public function getByEventProfile(){
    currentSubmission =  entityload("EventSubmission", { eventID = variables.eventID, profileID = variables.profileID }, true);
    if (!isObject(currentSubmission))
        currentSubmission = entityNew("EventSubmission");
    return currentSubmission;
}
```

Comment: FWIW, that is not how `isDefined` works. `isDefined` expects a simple string representing the *name* of a variable, not an object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `isDefined("currentSubmission")` (note the quotes) or slightly faster `structKeyExists(variables,"currentSubmission")`

Comment: Thenk Ben.. nope, same result with or without quotes.

Comment: Correction.  isDefined("currentSubmission"), using quotes..  did work  thanks Ben!!

Comment: Using `structKeyExists` is safer. `isDefined` may access variables outside the function local scope, sometimes leading to false positives. (Also, in case it is not a typo, be sure to scope all function local variables)

Comment: Leigh, thanks.  structkeyExists is also working, and have also moved everything to local scope, so now checking with ... if (!structKeyExists(local,"currentSubmission")), and that seems to be working perfectly.  thanks!

Comment: And of course you can add your scope to isDefined too but structKeyExists is faster, just less friendly. That's a great way to distinguish use cases though, one being scope-search friendly, the other, not.

Answer (score 6):

`isNull()` is the function you're looking for.

http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/CFMLRef/WSe9cbe5cf462523a0-3c4c0bb81223f1daffb-8000.html

**UPDATE:** Although `isDefined()` or `structKeyExists()` might work, `isNull()` is the *De facto* function for checking if `entityLoad()` found anything.  In fact, it was introduced in CF9 solely for doing this.

Comment: Thanks Henry.  !isNull(currentSubmission) seems to be returning positive, even though currentSubmission is holding a populated entity.  It looks like isNull is only checking to see if the value is Null or not.. not whether it is a populated entity or null.  but thanks anyway.

Comment: @Jason isn't that what you need? `isNull()` is like the opposite of `isDefined()` or `structKeyExists()`.  Use `IsNull()` instead of `!isObject()` in the code in the question should work just as well.

Comment: Thanks Henry. IsNull would be a lot tidier but didn't seem to behave right for me. Will take another look next time I'm in there and let you know.

Comment: @Jason, I'd suggest you to "var-scoped" your `currentSubmission` variable